# how to run vue app in the same domain with laravel sanctum for SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need help in running my Vue spa in the same domain as my laravel app , when running "npm run serve" in terminal I think it's working but when I go to the browser it's refusing connection. I haven't done the backend which I will use sanctum for handling API. Has anybody here have the same project working on like me? love to make conversations to solve this.
Thanks in advance
here is the vue.config.js file

```
 const path = require('path')
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    const createThemeColorReplacerPlugin = require('./config/plugin.config')

    function resolve (dir) {
      return path.join(__dirname, dir)
    }

    /**
     * check production or preview(pro.loacg.com only)
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    function isProd () {
      return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    }

    const assetsCDN = {
      css: [],
     // https://unpkg.com/browse/vue@2.6.10/
      js: [
        '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js',
        '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@3.1.3/dist/vue-router.min.js',
        '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.min.js',
        '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.19.0/dist/axios.min.js'
      ]
    }

    // webpack build externals
    const prodExternals = {
      vue: 'Vue',
      'vue-router': 'VueRouter',
      vuex: 'Vuex',
      axios: 'axios'
    }

    // vue.config.js
    const vueConfig = {
      configureWebpack: {
        // webpack plugins
        plugins: [
          // Ignore all locale files of moment.js
          new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
        ],
        // if prod is on, add externals
        externals: isProd() ? prodExternals : {}
      },

      chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.alias
          .set('@$', resolve('src'))

        const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg')
        svgRule.uses.clear()
        svgRule
          .oneOf('inline')
          .resourceQuery(/inline/)
          .use('vue-svg-icon-loader')
          .loader('vue-svg-icon-loader')
          .end()
          .end()
          .oneOf('external')
          .use('file-loader')
          .loader('file-loader')
          .options({
             name: 'assets/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
          })

        // if prod is on
        // assets require on cdn
        if (isProd()) {
          config.plugin('html').tap(args => {
            args[0].cdn = assetsCDN
            return args
          })
        }
      },

      css: {
         loaderOptions: {
          less: {
            modifyVars: {
              // less vars，customize ant design theme

              'primary-color': '#00B4E4',
              // 'link-color': '#F5222D',
              'border-radius-base': '4px'
            },
            javascriptEnabled: true
          }
        }
      },

    }
     if (process.env.VUE_APP_PREVIEW === 'true') {
       vueConfig.configureWebpack.plugins.push(createThemeColorReplacerPlugin())
     }
     module.exports = vueConfig
     module.exports = {
       devServer: {
         host: 'app.paymate-ui.test'
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use Laravel and Vue.js together in the same application folder?

Should be pretty easy then.

1. First off, build your application with Vue scaffolding for the frontend.
2. Then, make a route that redirects everything to a single controller method that returns a spa view. (Or use a closure)
3. In this view, include your app.js as an asset and include the main Vue component (something like `<app></app>`).
4. Then build your Vue app. All requests will now be forwarded to the spa view, which includes your app.js, which should bootstrap Vue.

Comment: so you mean to say I don't have to put the vue app in the same domain as my laravel/sanctum?

Comment: You could put it on a separate server. You could also put it in the resources/js folder of your Laravel installation.

Comment: I have also set up like this, using react,following with the sanctum docs,I can login successfully but subsequent requests to api returns 401.